# Unable to upload documents on NetDocuments

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am trying to integrate asp.net website with NetDocuments using Rest API. NetDocument has PBS(profile Based Security) in which user has to submit profile details at the time of uploading or creating a document.

Here in the code, profile is the Profile class object and i have added all the required profile values to that object. From Profile object i got profile Json string and at last i have added this json string as a parameter to the request.

**Code:**

```
public class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
    }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Matter { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("v1/Document", Method.POST);

    //set other Parameter

    Profile profile = new Profile();  
    profile.Tags = TextBox1.Text; 
    profile.Client = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value; 
    profile.Matter = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value; 
    profile.Author = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value; 
    profile.DocumentType = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value; 
    profile.Comments = TextBox2.Text; 
    var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); 
    string profileJsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(profile); 
    request.AddParameter("profile", profileJsonString);
    request.AddParameter("addToRecent", "true");
    request.AddParameter("failOnError", "true");
    var response = executeRequest(Request.QueryString["access_token"], request);
}
```

**Error:**

> {"error":"Invalid document profile information. Client requires a
>   value. Matter requires a value. Author requires a value. Document Type
>   requires a value."}

I am not sure what i am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you're using RestSharp, perhaps adding that tag will bring results.

Comment: @AjayBisht - Did the issue get solved ?

Comment: Got in to same problem. Which tag are you guys talking about? Can you response with code snippet as example. Much appreciated!